# How to check another column value while processing textfile sequentially in .net

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, text-files

I am reading text file which contains 100k entries and few are posted in question. I have to read only those records who is active 'Y' rest all I have to skip and if column value for `ASC` is `ASC10` or `ASC20` then I have to set a string variable named 'sss' value as "Flori" and if `ASC30` then I have to check other column named 'SAC' if its value is 3 then sss="Texi" else if  it is 4 then sss="Flori".

The following code will read text file and process but the two requirement I am not able to achieve it, since the values are in same row and retrieving values sequentially

Code I wrote is:

```
private static void Readfiles()
{
    string path = @"D:\study\Students.txt";
    string sss = string.Empty;
    System.Collections.ArrayList ar = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).Where(arg => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arg)).ToArray();
    string[] cols = lines[0]
        .Trim()
        .Split(new[] { '\t', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    int liness = 1;
    foreach (string line in lines.Skip(1))
    {
        string[] cells = line
            .Trim()
            .Split(new[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        for (int counter = 0; counter < cols.Length; counter++)
        {
            string cellValue = "N/A";
            if (counter < cells.Length)
                cellValue = cells[counter];
            Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", cols[counter],cellValue);
            if (cols[counter] == "ASC")
            {
                if (cellValue == "ASC10" || cellValue == "ASC20")
                {
                    sss = "Flori";
                }
                //Here i have to check other column named "SAC" but HOWWWWWWWWWWWWWW??????????????????????????????????/ because processing is sequential
                if (cellValue == "ASC30")
                {
                    sss = "Texi";
                }
            }
        }
        liness++;
    }
}
```

And text file format is

```
Firstname   lastname    ASC age salary  location    active  SAC

Tom jerry   ASC10   32  20000   NY  Y   3
Sam peter   ASC20   31  30000   KY  N   4
jason   sam ASC30   21  40000   JU  Y   3
jerry   Forman  ASC20   34  23456   KK  Y   4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For skipping non-active rows, get the index of the "active" column and check that value at the beginning of your foreach loop:

```
int indexActive = Array.indexOf(cols, "active");
if (indexActive >= 0 && indexActive < cells.Count() && cells[indexActive] == "N")
{
    continue; // this skips this round of the foreach loop and continues with the next one
}
```

Get the index of the SAC column and check the cell with that index from the current line, something like this (insert at your comment):

```
int indexSAC = Array.indexOf(cols, "SAC");
if (indexSAC >= 0 && indexSAC < cells.Count())
{
    if (cells[indexSAC] == "3")
    {
        sss = "Texi";
    }
    else if (cells[indexSAC] == "4")
    {
        sss = "Flori";
    }
}
```

The first line could also be inserted after you define your `cols` array so that you only do it once.

Comment: indexOf cannot be applied to string array.and more over how to skip avtive 'N' rows?

Comment: Right, you need static call `Array.indexOf(cols, "SAC")`, see my edit.

Comment: since my text file contains lakhs of lines how to skip rows having value 'N' for column name active

Comment: Skipping non-active rows also added (what do you mean by "lacs"?)

Comment: Changed, can you try again?

Comment: @ Raidri it is working fine, let me do some more test before accepting as answer

Comment: lacs means lakhs :) million. Is there any bad logic  exists here.SInce i am processing millions of lines is there any better way

Comment: For that better open a new question on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).